# NSXMLParser didStartElement getting attributeDict issue

Tags: ios, swift, nsxmlparser

I'm trying to get the attributeDict in the NSXMLParser didStartElement. My issue is I'm getting an error in calling the attributeDict (Could not find an overload for 'subscript' that accepts the supplied arguments). Am I calling the method right? I want to call all symbol keys and then add it to an array.

```
    func parser(parser: NSXMLParser!, didStartElement elementName: String!, namespaceURI: String!, qualifiedName qName: String!, attributes attributeDict: [NSObject : AnyObject]!)
{
    element = elementName

    if (elementName as NSString).isEqualToString("p")
    {
        println("Element's attributes are \(attributeDict)")
        //Result
        //Element's attributes are [bid: 1.16301, offer: 1.16321, symbol: EUR/USD]


        elements = NSMutableDictionary.alloc()
        elements = [:]
        title1 = NSMutableString.alloc()
        title1 = ""

        title1 = String(attributeDict["symbol"]) //Error
    }
}
```

Comment: first of all check if you are getting mutable dictionary ?? than find key "symbol" in that dictionary. than define  title1 = attributeDict["symbol"]! as NSMutableString

Answer (score 2, accepted):

i hope this fix your issue

```
title1 = attributeDict["symbol"]! as NSMutableString
```